# Enumerated list of displayed integration questions

Tags: math-mode, lists

How do I format a list of questions like this?

[image: desired results]

I'm getting the equation on a new line below the i) when using `enumerate` and `\list`.
I don't want to get rid of `\[` and `\]` either, as I like the long integral sign.
I get this instead:

[image: actual results]

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\displaystyle` to switch to the long integral:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item $\displaystyle \int\frac{2+x}{(1+x)^2}\mathrm{d}x$.

\item $\displaystyle \int\frac{2x^2}{1-x^2}\mathrm{d}x$.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of result]

Answer (score 2):

For numbered equations you should use like this you should use the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package.

For the lowercase roman letters instead of the arabic ones you can either use the following to enable it for the whole document

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\roman{equation}}
```

… or use a counter which you increment after every line and use the tag command—something like this (then you can also use `align*` which doesn't do numbering by default):

```
\newcounter{eq}
\setcounter{eq}{0}

\begin{align}
    ... \tag{\text{\roman{eq}}}\stepcounter{eq}\\
    ... \tag{\text{\roman{eq}}}\stepcounter{eq}\\
    ... \tag{\text{\roman{eq}}}
\end{align}
```

To get the equation numbers on the left, you have to add `leqno` to your document class options.

At the end there might be

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\roman{equation}}
...
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \int^\pi_0\frac{x\sin x}{3+\sin^2 x}\text{d}x\ \text{;}\\
        \int^{2\pi}_0\frac{x\sin x}{3+\sin^2 x}\text{d}x\ \text{;}\\
        \int^\pi_0\frac{x|\sin x|}{3+\sin^2 x}\text{d}x\ \text{.}
    \end{align}    
\end{document}
```